# Make folders accessible to select users only

Tags: php, web, directory, web-folders

My website has a form where users can upload documents. They are stored in the www.mysite.com/uploads folder.RIght now anyone who types that path in the brower can view those files. I was to make it so only people with access can view it. How would I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Use `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` - stop them right in their tracks.

Comment: But if they type in whole path i.e:www.mysite.com/uploads/name.doc wouldn't they still get access to it? And how would I allow the admin to still access the folder/files. I'm using php btw.

Comment: How is your PHP running? Using FastCGI or Apache?

Comment: @AshvicGodinho Doesn't matter if they do. Just keep all protected files inside the same folder and you'll be ok. Just make sure you protect the file itself or the entire folder. You can do either. How to allow the admin, well the admin would need to know the username and password to get in.

Comment: @AshvicGodinho Here is another option which is a password only access method. Unfortunately, the makers of `sas.php` are no longer offering the script. However someone did post it in another forum, and all you need to do is use this code on top of every page protected. `<?php require('sas.php'); ?>` then just hide your `.doc` inside a folder not viewable to the world and use a link inside the protected page and make the file downloadable. Here is the link http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?57288-SAS-script

Answer (score 0):

You should use .htaccess to manage all user with login and password.

More information on the link : http://www.elated.com/articles/password-protecting-your-pages-with-htaccess/

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: do not upload your files to a folder inside docroot. That is, if your document root is `/var/www/html`, make the upload location something like `/var/www/uploads`.

Step 2: Create a PHP file accessfile.php that authenticates admin and takes file name as `$_GET` parameter. e.g. http://site.com/accessfile.php?file=myfile.pdf

Inside accessfile.php, you may want to write a small program as below:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment");
file_get_contents("/var/www/uploads/{$file}");
```

Step 3: If admin needs to browse, create a quick browse option:

```
function &list_directory($dirpath) {
    if (!is_dir($dirpath) || !is_readable($dirpath)) {
        error_log(__FUNCTION__ . ": Argument should be a path to valid, readable directory (" . var_export($dirpath, true) . " provided)");
        return null;
    }
    $paths = array();
    $dir = realpath($dirpath);
    $dh = opendir($dir);
    while (false !== ($f = readdir($dh))) {
        if (strpos("$f", '.') !== 0) { // Ignore ones starting with '.'
            $paths["$f"] = "$dir/$f";
        }
    }
    closedir($dh);
    return $paths;
}
```